# how to open windows 10 ms-settings particular page without access to other settings

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

i have a winform application, in my application user can connect device to WiFi and can create hotspot, i open **ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot** from application

i don't want to let user, access other settings, how can i do this. in the picture below i want to hide options in red box

[image: hide access to other option when open **ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot**]

Comment: Speaking of the UI feature, It depends to availability of such feature in Windows. If it's not available you need implement the page yourself. Have you ever seen such behavior in any other software?

Comment: More of a Windows question, maybe belongs to https://superuser.com/

Comment: only in android

Comment: Just to confirm, is it a Windows Forms Application? (Not a Universal Windows Platform)

Comment: You can pass some options to [`Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync)

Comment: yes its a winform application

Answer (score 0):

With gpedit.msc you can define a rule to only show 'network-mobilehotspot'

[image]